# Graphiql returns all items instead of specific ones

Tags: javascript, node.js, graphql

I'm trying to get specific item by calling api and set arguments in query. I'm trying to use find function but it's giving me error when resolving query in graphiql.
This is my call api function with promise.

```
var request = require('request');

var options = { method: 'GET',
    url: 'myurl',
    qs: { searchCriteria: '' },
    headers:
        { 'postman-token': '12d2dbd7-6ea1-194c-ad38-5bffbac6706c',
            'cache-control': 'no-cache',
            authorization: 'Bearer b0kk2w8ptk9smhnl4ogh4y40adly0s5h',
            'content-type': 'application/json' } };

const getAllLinks = () => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        request(options, function (error, response, body) {
            //console.log(body);

            if (error) {
                reject(error);

            }

            else {

                const myJSON = JSON.parse(body);
                resolve(myJSON.items);
                //console.log(myJSON.items);




            }

        });

    });

};

const testAllLinks = () => {
  return getAllLinks().then((res) => {
      return res;
  })
};
```

Then here my resolver, query should return specific id of all items from api.

```
Query: {
        allItems: (_, { id }) => find(getAllLinks(), {id: id}),
```

But I'm keep getting error `Cannot return null for non-nullable field Query.allItems.` I'm allowing arguments in schema (`allItems(id: Int): [Item]!`).
When I change query in resolver to that:
`allItems: () => getAllLinks(), //or testAllLinks()` it return all items.


Here I created launchpad for this example with find function https://launchpad.graphql.com/r9wk3kpk8n and it works there, but not here...

Schema:

```
const typeDefs = `
    type Item  {
        id: ID!
        sku: String!
        name: String!
        attribute_set_id: Int!
        price: Float
        status: Int!
        visibility: Int!
        type_id: String!
        created_at: String!
        updated_at: String!
        product_links: [String]
        tier_prices: [Int]
        custom_attributes: [CUSTOM_ATTRIBUTES]
    }

    union CUSTOM_ATTRIBUTES = CustomString | CustomArray

   type CustomString {
    attribute_code: String
    value: String
  }

  type CustomArray {
    attribute_code: String
    value: [String]

  } 

  type Query {
    allItems(id: Int): [Item]!

  }
`;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your launchpad shows a schema with a query that resolves to a single type (`Author`). You didn't include the schema in your question, but I'm guessing the query `allItems` is supposed to return a List (something like `[Item]`). If GraphQL is expecting a List, then your resolver needs to return an array, not a single object.

Lodash's `find` (and the built-in array method for that matter) takes an array and returns a single item from that array. If it can't find an item meeting the criteria you specified, it will return undefined.

That means you probably want to use `filter`, not `find`, to reduce your array to just the items with the passed in id.

Additionally, `getAllLinks` returns a promise, so you need to have it resolve before using anything like `filter` or `find` to modify the result. Something like

```
allItems: (_, { id }) => getAllLinks().then(result => filter(result, {id: id}))
// or
allItems: async (_, { id }) => filter(await getAllLinks(), {id: id})
```

Comment: Hmm, I don't know, for me my schema looks the same as this, here from graphiql, take a look https://imgur.com/a/enbx6 - that's why I tried to use find function. Anyway, with filter function query returns null (hovewer in schema I specified [Item]!)

Comment: Also I have updated first post with schema included.  
`allItems: (_, { id }) => filter(getAllLinks(), {id: id}),` query returns nothing - `"allItems": []`

Comment: Oops, forgot your getAllLinks function was returning a Promise. See edit.